# How to Remove Firebase Database ChildByAutoId?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a database reference like this,

My Firebase Referance:

[image]

I want to delete the red area:

[image]

I am using to user authentication with e-mail.
My Code is here:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class bakimKayitlarimVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var todoList = [BakimlarListe]()
private var databaseHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!

var databaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadData()
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //I want to this code?? Please Help Me..

}
}



func loadData() {
    self.todoList.removeAll()
    let userReference = databaseRef.child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)")
    userReference.child("bakimlar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let todoDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,todoElement) in todoDict {
                print(todoElement);
                let todo = BakimlarListe()
                todo.bakimKm = todoElement["bakimkm"] as? String
                todo.sonrakiBakimKm = todoElement["sonrakibakimkm"] as? String
                todo.tarih = todoElement["tarih"] as? String
                todo.degisenler1 = todoElement["degisenler1"] as? String
                todo.degisenler2 = todoElement["degisenler2"] as? String
                todo.degisenler3 = todoElement["degisenler3"] as? String
                todo.degisenler4 = todoElement["degisenler4"] as? String
                todo.degisenler5 = todoElement["degisenler5"] as? String
                todo.degisenler6 = todoElement["degisenler6"] as? String
                todo.degisenler7 = todoElement["degisenler7"] as? String
                todo.degisenler8 = todoElement["degisenler8"] as? String
                todo.degisenler9 = todoElement["degisenler9"] as? String
                todo.degisenler10 = todoElement["degisenler10"] as? String
                todo.degisenler11 = todoElement["degisenler11"] as? String
                todo.degisenler12 = todoElement["degisenler12"] as? String
                todo.degisenlerDetay = todoElement["degisenlerDetay"] as? String
                self.todoList.append(todo)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.todoList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell


    // populate the data in your cell as desired
    cell.bakimKmLabel.text = todoList[indexPath.row].bakimKm
    cell.sonrakiBakimKmLabel.text = todoList[indexPath.row].sonrakiBakimKm
    cell.tarihLabel.text = todoList[indexPath.row].tarih
    cell.degisenler1Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler1
    cell.degisenler2Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler2
    cell.degisenler3Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler3
    cell.degisenler4Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler4
    cell.degisenler5Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler5
    cell.degisenler6Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler6
    cell.degisenler7Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler7
    cell.degisenler8Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler8
    cell.degisenler9Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler9
    cell.degisenler10Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler10
    cell.degisenler11Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler11
    cell.degisenler12Label.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenler12
    cell.degisenlerDetayLabel.text = todoList[indexPath.row].degisenlerDetay


    return cell
}
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bakimKmLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sonrakiBakimKmLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tarihLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler2Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler3Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler4Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler5Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler6Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler7Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler8Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenlerDetayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler9Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler10Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler11Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var degisenler12Label: UILabel!
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am waiting... Please help..

Comment: Did you found a solution to your question? I have the same problem as you